# Convert * in path to Regex

Tags: regex, path

we need **to exclude** several folder from backup and **we can use RegexExcludeList**.
*(our magento create a lot of session files and we need to exclude from backup)*

Our situation is this:
**we want to exclude all these folders**:

- /opt/www/*/prod/htdocs/var/session
- /opt/www/*/dev/htdocs/var/session
- /opt/www/*/htdocs/var/session

**How to with Regex?**

I'm trying to match using this website: https://regex101.com/

Thank you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Solve it with this:

```
\/opt\/www\/[\S]+\/htdocs\/var\/session
```

Comment: You can use `\/opt\/www\/[^\/]+\/htdocs\/var\/session`